# PyQt5 - Implement thread to stop UI from freezing

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I work on a simple PyQt5 app that connects to a remote host, and install a package on it using snmp, ssh.

Basicaly, the user write the ip address, press the start button, and here goes the magic !
My script works fine, but it freezes during the main function because I don't use threading. It freezes when it arrives to the part "status_copy" of start_process function.

I've tried to implement threading but I face a lot of issues and can't find a way to solve it now.
Here's a part of the code for the thread worker that I wrote.

```
class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def run(self):
        start_process(ui)

def test_thread(ui):
    ui.button_start.setEnabled(False)
    ui.thread = QtCore.QThread()
    ui.worker = WorkerThread()
    ui.worker.moveToThread(ui.thread)

    ui.thread.started.connect(ui.worker.run)
    ui.worker.finished.connect(ui.thread.quit)
    ui.worker.finished.connect(ui.worker.deleteLater)
    ui.thread.finished.connect(ui.thread.deleteLater)

    ui.thread.start()
```

And now the other main part of the script. I know, the function start_process itself is really messy but I didn't take time to simplify it.

```
def set_ui (ui):
    # Menubar behavior
    ui.action_exit.triggered.connect(sys.exit)

    # Screenshot View Behavior
    position = ui.gridLayout.getItemPosition(ui.gridLayout.indexOf(ui.screenshot_view))
    ui.screenshot_view = QWebEngineView(ui.centralwidget)
    ui.gridLayout.addWidget(ui.screenshot_view, position[0], position[1], position[2], position[3])

    # Button behavior
    ui.button_start.setEnabled(False)
    ui.button_screenshot.setEnabled(False)
    ui.button_reboot.setEnabled(False)
    # ui.button_start.clicked.connect(lambda x : start_process(ui))
    ui.button_start.clicked.connect(lambda x : test_thread(ui))
    ui.button_clear.clicked.connect(lambda x : clear_output(ui))
    ui.button_screenshot.clicked.connect(lambda x : update_screenshot(ui))
    ui.button_reboot.clicked.connect(lambda x : reboot_equipment(ui))
    ui.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(lambda x : select_siv(ui))

    # Entry behavior
    ui.entry_equipment.textChanged.connect(lambda x : validate_name_input(ui, x))
    ui.entry_serialnumber.textChanged.connect(lambda x : validate_serial_number_input(ui, x))

    # Instance variables
    ui.ip_address = None
    ui.username = None
    ui.password = None
    ui.entry_name_set = False
    ui.entry_serial_number_set = False
    ui.constructor = None
    ui.siv = (ui.buttonGroup.checkedButton()).text()

    ui.label_version.setText(f'Version {APP_VERSION}')
    
# UI functions

def start_process(ui):
    """
    Launch the process once the start button is pressed.
    """

    convert_sn_to_fqdn(ui)

    # Perform ping test
    if features.test_ping(ui.ip_address):
        write_output(ui, '- Ping OK.')
        ui.progressBar.setProperty('value', 15)
        ui.constructor = find_constructor(ui)
        match ui.constructor:
            case '1':
                write_output(ui, '- Deployment soft 1.')
                write_output(ui, '- Installation.')
            case '2':
                write_output(ui, '- Deployment soft 2.')
                write_output(ui, '- Installation.')
            case _:
                write_output(ui, '- Error : Unknown constructor.')
        if ui.constructor:
            ui.progressBar.setProperty('value', 40)
            status_copy = copy_file(ui, ui.constructor) 
            if status_copy == True:
                ui.progressBar.setProperty('value', 70)
                match ui.constructor:
                    case '1':
                        match ui.siv:
                            case 'a':
                                param_install = 'stuff_a'
                            case 'b':
                                param_install = 'stuff_b'

                        features.snmpset(ui.ip_address, '%OID%', param_install)
                        features.snmpset(ui.ip_address, '%OID', '1')
                    case '2':
                        match ui.siv:
                            case 'a':
                                param_install = 'stuff_ab'
                            case 'b':
                                param_install = 'stuff_bb'
                        # Set SNMP stuff
                        features.snmpset(ui.ip_address, '%OID%', 'X')
                        features.snmpset(ui.ip_address, '%OID%', '1')
                        # Tempo 5s
                        time.sleep(5)
                        # Set other SNMP stuff
                        features.snmpset(ui.ip_address, '%OID%', param_install)
                        features.snmpset(ui.ip_address, '%OID%', '1')

                write_output(ui, '- Copy finished, wait until the end of the installation on the equipment.')
                write_output(ui, '- A check of the installation status will be performed in 60 seconds.')
                time.sleep(60)
                result_install = features.snmpget_result_install(ui.ip_address, ui.constructor)
                if 'OK' in result_install:
                    write_output(ui, '- Installation successful')
                elif 'KO' in result_install:
                    write_output(ui, '- Installation failed')
                else:
                    i = 1
                    # Check installation status every 10 seconds for 1 minute in case it takes longer
                    while i != 6 and result_install == '':
                        time.sleep(10)
                        write_output(ui, f'- Installation still ongoing. Please wait. {i}/6')
                        result_install = features.snmpget_result_install(ui.ip_address, ui.constructor)
                        i += 1
                    if i == 6:
                        write_output(ui, '- Installation corrupted')
                    elif 'OK' in result_install:
                        write_output(ui, '- Installation successful')
                    else:
                        write_output(ui, '- Installation failed')

                ui.button_screenshot.setEnabled(True)
                ui.button_reboot.setEnabled(True)
                update_screenshot(ui)
            else:
                write_output(ui, '- Deplyment error')
        ui.progressBar.setProperty('value', 100)
    else:
        write_output(ui, f'- Ping KO. {ui.ip_address}')
        ui.progressBar.setProperty('value', 100)
        features.send_artium_response(
            sn=ui.entry_serialnumber.text(), 
            dauphine=ui.entry_equipment.text(), 
            cp=os.getlogin(), 
            constructor=ui.constructor, 
            result='KO - Connection failed'
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('%NAME')

    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Window()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    set_ui(ui)

    # Move window to the center of the screen
    frame_geometry = window.frameGeometry()
    center_position = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    frame_geometry.moveCenter(center_position)
    window.move(frame_geometry.topLeft())

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hopping you can help me on this !

Comment: It's not really clear where the problem is, and, sincerely, the fact that you didn't take your time to improve the function doesn't really help us: StackOverflow is not a debugging or code review service. In any case, if you're trying to use threading to access the UI or even create UI elements, that's not an option: widgets are ***not*** thread safe, and can only be created in the thread of the QApplication.

Comment: [Use PyQt's QThread to Prevent Freezing GUIs](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/).

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't specify what issues you are having after implementing threading, I will provide you with a template that I use when adding threading.

```
import sys
import traceback
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QThreadPool
from mywindow import Ui_MainWindow


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(dict)
    finished = pyqtSignal()


class Worker(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
        
    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            result = self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            try:
                self.signals.result.emit(result)
            except Exception:
                pass
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUI(self)
        
        self.ui.button.clicked.connect(self.start_worker)
        
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
    
    def thread_result(self, result):
        # result is a dict based on WorkerSignals()
        print(result)
    
    def thread_error(self, err):
        # err is a tuple based on WorkerSignals()
        print(err)
    
    def thread_finished(self):
        print('Thread complete')
    
    def start_process(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # other stuff here
    
    def start_worker(self):
        worker = Worker(self.start_process) # add args or kwargs as necessary
        worker.signals.result.connect(self.thread_result)
        worker.signals.error.connect(self.thread_error)
        workers.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_finished)
        
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
```